# -[NSAttributedString boundingRectWithSize] rect is wrong of html

Tags: ios

if the html element is `<p>` or `<div>` the rect will be wrong.

if the html element is `<span>` the rect will be right.

eg.

http://test-1252137158.file.myqcloud.com/myFloder/WX20180717-112628%402x.png

http://test-1252137158.file.myqcloud.com/myFloder/WX20180717-112649%402x.png

http://test-1252137158.file.myqcloud.com/myFloder/WX20180717-112706%402x.png

code:

https://github.com/HJaycee/questions/blob/master/iOS_attributedString/rich_html/rich_html/ViewController.m

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
NSRange tailRange = NSMakeRange(attributedString.length - 1, 1);
if (attributedString.length > 1 &&
    [[[attributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:tailRange] string] isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:tailRange withString:@""];
}

CGRect rect = [self.attributeString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width,     CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:NULL];

ceilf(rect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass also the flag `NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading` to take into account the font used.

Something like this (line 41):

```
CGRect rect = [str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, CGFLOAT_MAX)
options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
context:NULL];
```